# Bounding $\zeta$ from below

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta

I am interested in proving a formula for the integrated Chebyshev function
$$\psi_1(x) = \int_1^x\psi(t)dt$$
that is a sum of all residues of the function
$$f(s) = \frac{x^{s + 1}}{s(s + 1)}\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}.$$
I know that
$$\psi_1(x) = -\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c - i\infty}^{c + i\infty}f(s)ds$$
for $c > 1$, and that you can let $c = 1$ to get a contribution of $\textrm{Res}_{s = 1}f(s) = x^2/2$ from the pole at $s = 1$. So to prove my formula I want to consider a rectangular contour whose right side is the line $\textrm{Re}(s) = 1$ and then show that the integral of $f(s)$ vanishes as you let the side lengths go to infinity.

What I wanted to do is use that
$$\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} = \frac{d}{ds}\log\zeta(s).$$
I can then get the necessary estimates for $f(s)$ by estimating $\zeta(s)$. But this would require a lower bound on $\zeta(s)$ to ensure that it's not going to $0$. Any suggestions?

EDIT: By taking the logarithmic derivative of the functional equation and estimating each term separately, I believe I have reduced the problem to estimating $\zeta'/\zeta$ on the parts of the contour lying in the critical strip, that is, on lines from $1 + iT$ to $iT$ and from $-iT$ to $1 - iT$.

Comment: To be clear: Along what line do you want to perform your integration?

Comment: what kind of bound you want? i guess something beta then $1<|\zeta(s)|$

Comment: The line from $1 + it$ to $n + it$, the line from $n + it$ to $n - it$, and the line from $n - it$ to $1 - it$, where $n$ is an odd integer so I avoid the poles of $f(s)$ at negative even integer $s$. I then want to let $n$ and $t$ go to infinity.

Comment: So, this sort of computation has been done in quite a few textbooks. Would a pointer to one of those sources suffice for you?

Comment: Yeah, that would be helpful.

Comment: I don't follow your contour. What you need is looking at $\psi_1(x) -\frac{x^2}{2}= \int_{2-i\infty}^{2+i\infty}(\frac{-\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}\frac{1}{s(s+1)}-\frac{1/2}{s-1})x^{s+1}ds$ and shift the contour to the boundary of the zero-free region $\sigma > 1-\frac{A}{\log |t|+B}$, and show  the bound  $|\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}- \frac{1}{|s-1|}| = \mathcal{O}(\log^k(|t|+C)$ on the zero-free region, [for example see there p.12-...](https://apps.carleton.edu/curricular/math/assets/smithry_2009.pdf)

Comment: Or maybe you want the explicit formula $\psi_1(x) = \frac{x^2}{2}-\sum_\rho \frac{x^{\rho+1}}{\rho (\rho+1)}$, in that case it depends on what you proved, and see [there p.3](http://math.stanford.edu/~brubaker/pnt.pdf)